# Error using If not Is Nothing logical function to delete rows with value of zero

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-statements, rows

I wrote a code to delete rows in which 13rd column has a value of 0, subject to column 10 and 11 not being nothing. The code is the following:

```
Option Explicit

Sub deletezero()

Dim i As Integer

Worksheets("1. Con.SECTORIAL & EMISOR").Activate

For i = 1 To 200

    If Cells(i, 13).Value = 0 And Not Cells(i, 10) Is Nothing And Not Cells(i, 11) Is Nothing Then
    Rows(i).Select
    Selection.Delete
    End If

    Next i

End Sub
```

Instead of getting the expected, the sub delete rows even if columns 10 and 11 aren't nothing and after a few deletes I get the

> error 13: type doesn't match

Could someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

When you deleting rows, loop from the last to the first.

```
For i = 200 to 1 Step -1
```

Also, there is no need of selecting here, just:

```
Rows(i).Delete
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm conscius it is not necessary to use Rows(i).Select, but since there is no way to track the code development, If I run it while watching the Excel sheet it acts as a kind of visual help to do it.